# Protection from leaking capacitors - store upside down?

Tags: capacitor, electrolytic-capacitor, damage, storage

I collect many vintage computers.  Most of them use through-hole capacitors, some axial, etc.  Some also use SMD caps.

When I store my computers, I always remove any batteries.

Anyway, I was wondering if storing my computers upside down would reduce the chances of a leak causing damage to the computer.

I realize capacitors leak.  Even while in storage.  But if it were upside down, it seems that the electrolyte would run down the side of the cap (onto the plastic top case, mind you).  Obviously, a SMD cap or any cap that is flush with the board would still get some electrolyte on the motherboard.  But shouldn't it be reduced to a smaller area?

Or, is this a crazy idea that has no real advantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems viable to me... Hopefully dead ones will be detectable upon inspection.

Just guessing here but here may be 'some' capillary action on the leads of the cap causing corrosion or whatever with electrolyte moving up but I would think it would be restricted to the leads / pads of the cap.

Unless they start making electrolytics with 'anti-gravity' electrolytes, its only logical that the majority of the expelled liquid would be drawn down and away from the board.